# Strings are lists but i cannot use list methods on them like append or replace. Why?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to make a palindrome from a user input. I was thinking I could use .replace() but I got an error that 'str' object has no attribute 'append'. I thought strings were lists? So why don't list methods work on them?

Comment: Nope, strings are not lists.

Comment: Strings are sequences, like lists. Read about `list()` in the docs.

Comment: strings are not lists. If you want to add text at the end of a string use `+` e.g. `str1+str2`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 4):

Strings are not lists, they are sequences. They share some of the same behaviors as lists, but they are not themselves lists. Strings are immutable objects.

You can convert a string to a list by passing the string to `list`:

```
data = list("some string")
```

You can then operate on `data`, and convert it back to a string later with `join`:

```
new_string = "".join(data)
```

If you simply want to add a character to a string you can use concatenation:

```
new_string = "abc" + "d"
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are a distinct class from Lists. As the error says, Strings don't have an `append` method.

`append` wouldn't make sense for Strings anyways, as they're immutable. They can't be modified in place like lists can.

If you want to "append" a Character, just use concatenation, and reassign the String:

```
x = "String" + "s"
```

Answer (score 0):

To get things clear, `str` and `list` are two different data types.

One basic difference between str's and lists is that lists can any type of data i.e. integers, characters, dictionary or another list etc., while strings can only hold a set of characters(alphabets numbers or any special characters).

Also, lists are mutable and string are immutable!

[Reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)

To get to know what methods can be used with a string `dir(str)` and `dir(list)` would help!

Answer (score 0):

**Tl;dr: `strings` != `lists`.**

You can index individual characters in `strings`, like you can index elements in `lists`, but there is a difference in **mutability**.

If something is mutable, it can change. `Lists` are *mutable* so you can change the contents of them (either adding, removing or changing elements).

See some examples that I am sure you are familiar with:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l[0] = 9
>>> l.append(8)
>>> l
[9, 2, 3, 8]
```

On the other hand, `strings` are *immutable* so can **not** change. This means that there are no `append` or equivalent methods. However, you can `concatenate` two of them to form a *new* string, but this is a different operation in terms of memory (appending modifies the current space in memory, concatenation assigns a whole new space in memory to the new string).

So here are some examples with `strings`:

```
>>> s = "abcdef"
>>> s += "ghi"
>>> s
'abcdefghi'
>>> s[0] = "z"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's `type()` method to figure out what type the object is:

```
>>> type("String")
<class 'str'>
```

You can also turn the string into a list using the list method:

```
>>> type(list("String"))
<class 'list'>
```